# Trying ubuntu from liveUSB: Input signal out of range

Tags: boot, nvidia, live-usb

I've got a computer with UEFI-BIOS and NVidia Geforce gtx1080 connected to it.

With Unetbootin created a liveUSB with ubuntu 16.04, tried to launch ubuntu.
It freezed on the [Unebootin default screen](https://www.tenuz.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Unetbootin-From-Boot-Menu.png)

Then tried to boot it adding nomodeset option, and that led to "Input signal out of range, Change settings to 1600x900 -60Hz".

Where can I change the type of input signal?

GPU is connected correctly (was tested on Windows before Win was removed from this PC)

Comment: I am not really sure why you thought the boot froze. Just select what you want (e.g. Try Ununtu) with the up/down curser keys, and press "ENTER", which will then continue.

Comment: @ridgy, I pressed "enter" in both cases after choosing the option I want, boot started, but in 1st case it looked freezed: only blinking cursor under the Unetbootin screen for 20 minutes, and no reaction to any key combination